# Push temporary git branch to remote without files or changes

Tags: git, git-branch

We have a git `master` branch. From this branch we create feature branches and merge those feature branches into master.

We need now a 'temporary' branch from where we branch off some feature branches. Those feature branches will be merged into the `temporary` branch.

How do I push the new 'temporary' branch (without any files or changes) too remote so others are also able to branch off this branch?

Comment: Your problem isn't clear. What's the trouble? This sounds like a run-of-the-mill branch push.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, these are the steps:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b temporary
git push -u origin temporary
```

Then, any developer should do this:

```
git fetch
git checkout temporary
git checkout -b myNewBranch
<< user does things >>
```